# Complete beginner needs advice/help on how to install an RFID reader

Tags: card-reader

So the powers-that-be recently decided that I would lead a project we have that has to do with reading RFID tags, however I have no experience or knowledge to as where I should begin. All I know is that they rigged up some connection via VGA and the computer reads it through HyperConnect. The thing is the reading I'm doing seems to indicate that I need to make some other thing to connect to the RFID reader and program that board to interpret said connection, correct?

Here's what it looks like: [pics](http://imgur.com/a/4DnLg)

[image]
[image]

It's a no name chinese RFID reader as far as I can tell. Any guidance is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit: I was directed here from SO, if there's a better forum to post this to please let me know.

Comment: It's probably not VGA, but instead a Serial port. that and you question is REALLY hard to follow.  What exactly are you trying to do _right now_?  What have you tried so far?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Is it connected by serial, and using the HyperTerminal program on the PC? That would make more sense than VGA.

Comment: @techie007 Right now I'm trying to get this thing to give me an output via software.

Comment: @techie007 *accidentally pressed enter* What I've tried was only the set-up they gave me yesterday. They hook it up via VGA and run HyperConnect, I can scan a bracelet but it outputs gibberish. 

I'm guessing HyperConnect is the wrong software to use and from what daxlerod has said I should be connecting it to a serial port which is what Im going to research now (on how to connect those wires to serial port). 

Sorry for any confusion, English is not my first language.

Comment: @daxlerod It is not connect by serial, which is what I should be doing I'm assuming? Ill see if there's a way I can hook this up to a serial port.

Comment: Wow.. just wow.. this is a messy nightmare of a hack job left up to someone with no experience. GOOD LUCK, I'm out. :)

Comment: What makes you think they are using a VGA connection?  It looks like the device cable was modified.  I don't think we can help you.  This sort of thing is unique.  Who made these modifications to this device?  Why don't you go out and purchasse and actual solution instead of using a hacked together solution that will eventually fail because all hardware fails and now you have an unidentifiedable device.

Comment: @Ramhound They only soldered the cables from the reader to the pins inside the VGA, the cables goes to the computer via VGA as well. I would like to go out and purchase a solution, but I have no way to know where, to make things worse I'm in Mexico sooooo yeah.

Comment: @nitrous - There are dozens of USB RFID readers for very cheap. How are we suppose to tell you how to read the data if you don't even understand what was done? Can you even tell us which vga pins are even connected? **I do believe Amazon ships to Mexico.**  I did a rough estimate for under $50 you can have an actual device that works shipped to you.

Answer (score 1):

As per the advice of Ramhound, as well as comments from techie007, what you need to do is go back to the Powers-That-Be, and tell them you need to start this project from scratch, from the ground up.  You **need** to do this for a few reasons...

1. The current RFID reading hardware has no documentation for you to familiarize yourself with.
2. The current RFID reading hardware is cobbled together in a hap-hazard fashion, with the emphasis on *hazard*.
3. The project needs to have a budget that you can work within, that will actually allow for the completion of the project.
4. Since you have been handed this project, and you are new to the hardware, software, and technology involved, you need to be able to use hardware and software that has documentation you can follow, to allow you to actually complete the project.
5. The Powers-That-Be will appreciate being able to maintain this project, regardless of whether you are attached to it, if the hardware and software involved can be easily replaced in case of failure, and the documentation for said hardware and software is readily available.  Moreover, your notes on getting it all to work would make it much easier for the next person in the future.

Now, all of these things apply, because of the following:

1. You aren't even sure how the RFID reader is connected to the computer, and... let's face it... there aren't many VGA **INPUTS** on a computer.  It is not to say you are wrong that it is using a VGA cable, but that means there is some other device in the computer that has a VGA input, and that is **not** standard and should have documentation.
2. If you yourself have to come at this from the ground up, the equipment you are working with should also be as new to the project as you are.  Granted, others have been thrust into projects where they are expected to take over where someone left off, but that implies there was a substantial investment that needed to be protected by NOT starting with all new hardware.  This doesn't apply when you are dealing with a no-name RFID reader connected by soldered cabled and loose wires that was quite possibly thrown together from what someone found in a donation bin.

In short, this is one of those times it is acceptable to turn around and tell your superior "I am happy to take on this project.  We need to scrap what we have, and start over."